# Ошибка при наследовании в Python

Tags: python, ооп

Пытаюсь разобраться с наследованием в Python. Столкнулся с тем, что при попытке вызвать переменные из родителей, могу вызвать только переменную `a` и собственно переменную `f`, с вызовом методов так же. Чем это вызвано (Если не сложно, то хотелось бы почитать источники с действительно полезной информацией), и можно ли как то это исправить чтобы из всех классов вызывались методы и переменные?

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class b:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2

    def b_print(self):
        print(self.b)
        
class c:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 3
    
class f(a, b, c):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.f = 4
        
    def pprint(self):
        try:
            print(self.a)
        except:
            print('a: Не обнаружено')
        try:
            print(self.b)
        except:
            print('b: Не обнаружено')
        try:
            print(self.c)
        except:
            print('c: Не обнаружено')
        try:
            print(self.f)
        except:
            print('f: Не обнаружено')
            
        
cl = f()
print(f.__mro__)
cl.pprint()
cl.b_print()
```

Вывод кода:

```
(<class '__main__.f'>, <class '__main__.a'>, <class '__main__.b'>, <class '__main__.c'>, <class 'object'>)
1
b: Не обнаружено
c: Не обнаружено
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\DEV\oop\test.py", line 43, in <module>
    cl.b_print()
  File "c:\DEV\oop\test.py", line 10, in b_print
    print(self.b)
AttributeError: 'f' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Comment: переменные класса наследуются, а конструкторы придется ручками запускать, если нужен не только первый (могу соврать :) )

Comment: вроде, не соврал - https://pythonim.ru/osnovy/mnozhestvennoe-nasledovanie-python

Comment: @splash58 т.е тут нужно использовать не super().__init__() а что-то  такое? 
a.__init__(self) b.__init__(self) c.__init__(self)

Comment: ага, именно так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

т.к `super()` берет только первого родителя, то как заметил @splash58, тут нужно будет делать руками, но если такой возможности нет, можно сделать так:

```py
class D(A, B, C):
    
    def __init__(self):
        for parent in self.__bases__:
            parent.__init__(self)
```

Comment: хотя это и не очень явно

Comment: не думал что по классам родителей можно циклом пройтись)
спасибо, вроде бы как понял, буду пробовать)